# ScrollView with flex 1 makes it un-scrollable

Tags: flexbox, react-native, react-native-scrollview

I'm trying to run flex on a `ScrollView`, and as long as the ScrollView has `flex: 1` the **scroll inside does not work**. 
here is the expo fiddle (that you can run this code and play with)
https://snack.expo.io/SySerKNp-

note that if you remove the `flex: 1` from the `ScrollView` it does let scroll but then you lose the flex power ( the ability to let the red container down to push up the upper box (the ScrollView) ) so I must have a flex there.

p.s - I'm working only on android, and I haven't tested it on iPhone( I don't mind the result there )

any idea what am I missing ? why the `ScrollView` won't function right when it has a `flex: 1` ?
thanks !

Comment: How to run code at _snack_? ... also not sure, though I think you needed to wrap the `ScrollView` in a `View`

Comment: Did you try adding `flex: 1` to the outer most `View`?

Comment: @LGSon yes I tried it still doesn't work right, either way I'm losing the flex or the scroll.

Comment: And when you wrapped the `ScrollView` in a `View`, note that it is the `View` that should have `flex: 1`

Comment: yeah as you can see in line 34 the root `View` has `flex: 1`

Comment: No, don't mean that, I mean to wrap the `ScrollView` in a `View` of its own,  and that `View` should have `flex: 1`

Comment: and btw I have no choice but to wrap the `ScrollView` with a `View` as I have another `View` after it (the red box that supposed to push up)

Comment: Why can't you do that? ...and that might be needed to fix this, like this: https://snack.expo.io/HkNEysN6-

Comment: how come ? the return value needs to be properer JSX or you use one Component or you use a wrapper Component (In case of more - like mine .. I have a ScrollView and a View under it).

Comment: So this doesn't work? https://snack.expo.io/HkNEysN6-

Comment: @LGSon, I just tried the example you linked, as you can see you are losing the flex there (you can not see the green bottom border of the ScrollView) and red box is going over it instead of pushing it up.

Comment: No, can't see anything as I don't have a React environment to test it with, so I just apply standard Flexbox behavior to the code base

Comment: @LGSon, inside the link you have down a 'preview' option that opens an emulator, and you can play with it.

Comment: @LGSon,thanks for the reply but I don't see anything wrong with the code that I posted, I guess it's something about `ScrollView` component that I'm missing.

Comment: This border thing appears to me as an effect from not having `box-sizing: border-box`, so adding the extra `view` and set the border on it seems to work: https://snack.expo.io/r1-Ewj4Tb

Comment: @LGSon, this way the flex works on the `View`, but I'm losing the location on the current scroll in the `ScrollView` thats why I insist to make the flex on the ScrollView itself (so the ScrollView will be pushed up). as I said It's not a flex-box issue its more of react-native's ScrollView component issue.

Comment: @Danny It is because of the way that ScrollView works internally. Please explain what is it that you want to accomplish. Do you want to show a list of boxes above the red box? What is the thing that is not working right now? (Note: If I click on the red box nothing happens in the last expo)

Comment: @sfratini you have to click on the text "Click" to get the red box to grow. I believe what Danny wants is for the red box at the bottom to push up on the ScrollView, making it smaller (shorter) with each "Click" but also have the items inside scrollable.

Comment: Got it. I just posted something I believe fixes the issue.

Comment: @Danny try to change flex: 1 to flexGrow: 1 in the scrollview style. That should work I guess.

Comment: @Danny did you try the above solution as it is working for me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are telling the ScrollView to occupy all available space with flex=1 but the thing is that ScrollView works differently. It automatically renders all its children so it does work different with flex. That is the difference against a normal ListView or FlatList which have better performance.

I believe this snack solves that issue:  https://snack.expo.io/SkxN9GOT-

Basically, I am getting the height of the device and setting the ScrollView with a fixed height, based on (screenHeight - the current height of the red box).

Comment: Nicely done. I was planning to take the same approach, but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 125):

Try using flexGrow: 1 instead of flex: 1 in scrollView content container style as follows.

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, borderColor: 'green', borderWidth: 5 }}>
  <View style={styles.box1} />
  <View style={styles.box2} />
  <View style={styles.box1} />
</ScrollView>
```

https://snack.expo.io/HkkEVoh6Z

Comment: This is the answer. I was able to resolve the same problem with this. Read more about flex-grow and you'll understand that.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Works perfectly and avoids extra views and unnecessary logic

Comment: i can also confirm that this should be the accepted answer

Comment: can you tell the difference of using flex and flex grow in this case

Comment: I will leave that to community because I have not worked on react from last 5 years. Maybe you can read about it on web.

Answer (score 5):

The best thing to do is to **wrap your ScrollView in a View** and control that view with flex, your scroll view will follow.

This is a little example

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column',}}>

          <View style={{flex:5, backgroundColor : 'green' }}>
            <ScrollView style={{margin:50, backgroundColor : 'pink' }}>

              <Text> Hello Scroll View </Text>
              <Text> Hello Scroll View </Text>
              <Text> Hello Scroll View </Text>
              <Text> Hello Scroll View </Text>
              <Text> Hello Scroll View </Text>
              <Text> Hello Scroll View </Text>

            </ScrollView>
          </View>

          <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor : 'blue' }}>
              <Text> Hello Static View </Text>
          </View>

</View>
```

Answer (score 4):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46859086/8774386) has already been provided how to do it.

But here's an explanation why you cannot do by your method. The styles given in `contentContainerStyle` is

> applied to the scroll view content container which wraps all of the child views.

So when you apply `flex: 1` to `contentContainer` it takes full height of `ScrollView` whose height is also `flex: 1` as its parent `View`.

You can also simulate -

> the ability to let the red container down to push up the upper box

by adding a parent to `ScrollView` and apply style in the parent

```
<View style={styles.root}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, borderColor: 'green', borderWidth: 5 }}>
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.box1} />
      <View style={styles.box2} />
      <View style={styles.box1} />
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
  <View style={{ height: this.state.height, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ height: this.state.height + 10 })}>
      <Text>Click</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one it will 100% solve your problem

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View,ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default class AlignItemsBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // Try setting `alignItems` to 'flex-start'
      // Try setting `justifyContent` to `flex-end`.
      // Try setting `flexDirection` to `row`.
      <View style={{ flex: 1,flexDirection: 'column' }}>
        <View style={{   height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
        <View style={{  flex: 1,  backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} >
            <ScrollView>

<View style={{  flexDirection: 'column' , minHeight: 'fit-content'}} >
 <View style={{    height:150, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
    <View style={{ minHeight: 'fit-content', backgroundColor: '#fe3222' }} />      

 <View style={{    height:150, backgroundColor: '#fff222'}} />
    <View style={{    height:150, backgroundColor: '#555222'}} />           
              </View>

  </ScrollView>
 </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AlignItemsBasics);
```

Answer (score 0):

`flex:1` equals to `flexGrow:1 flexShrink:1 flexBasis:0`;

`flexGrow:1` equals to `flexGrow:1 flexShrink:0 (default value) flexBasis:0`.

So setting `flex:1` makes ScrollView content shrink to its parent and so unscrollable.